# In the prequel, "I Did NOT Give That Spider Superhuman Intelligence!", what are the references to future events and characters?

Tags: reference, dont-tell-my-parents

*[I Did NOT Give That Spider Superhuman Intelligence!](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LYNX2DQ)* is fourth book of the "Don't Tell My Parents" series by Richard Roberts, and is a prequel to the events of the first four books, taking place in the 1980s rather than in the 2000s. I can recognize some of the references, but I'm sure that I'm missing someone.

Specifically, are there any references to Brainy Ack and The Audit, Penny's parents?

Items I've noticed (spoilers ahoy!):

- Goodnight, as Fae, has been mentioned in the series before, as has Bull and his little sister Polly Vinyl Chloride.
- Goodnight gets a car from The Expert as he's just starting to come into his own and has chosen his name.
- We get the origin of Spider as a lab experiment.
- We get the beginnings of Spider as a crime boss and the beginnings of the pact between superheroes and supervillains to keep things from getting personal.
- We get Mourning Dove's origin, as was an explanation that she really is the enforcer for the pact.
- We see the genesis of Gerty Goat's Family Farm and its animatronics

Comment: I don't know about Akk and the Audit, but the villain Mammon promises to summon "a being of black fire, a true fallen angel." Lucyfar, perhaps?

Comment: @Adamant: Would you be "Discar" from the TVTropes forum? They made the same suggestion.

Comment: I have read three books but not the fourth once I do I will answer this question.

Comment: I thought that Brainy ack and The Audit came were superheros in the 90s if that is the case I that might be why there not in it. Personally I would love to read another book about the  Audit and Brainy before penny's birth.

Comment: Frankly, I was thrilled to catch the Gerty Goat reference. :)

Comment: Psychopomp was mentioned in don't tell my parents I have henchman. When the bull was trying to convince Claudia that she shouldn't be a superhero.

Comment: And if you’ve read the most recent book, you might have noticed that Mammon himself turned up there...

Comment: @Adamant: You are right. I didn't think to update the question with that. Do you want to post that as an answer, or should I just update the question?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I’ll answer when I’ve had more sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got most of the references. Other ones include:

- Sister Marianne is mentioned.
- Delicious, the supervillain made of candy, was mentioned in *Please Don’t Tell My Parents I’ve Got Henchmen*.

  > Red Eye pointed through the opposite wall. “They’ll be out by the
  >   monster cages. Someone brought a cake. Delicious is supposed to jump
  >   out of it and punch him in the face.”
  >
  > <sub>*Please Don’t Tell My Parents I’ve Got Henchmen*</sub>

  She also appears several times in IDNGTSSI. Her first reference:

  > That got him jutting out his chin indignantly. It was a good, strong
  >   chin, and like I said, any day now the rest of him would match it. For
  >   now, it made him look Psychopomop’s age. Er, the same age Psychopomp
  >   looks. “Salvaged! His wheels got blown up when Atomo went on that
  >   rampage last month. Neon Rider didn’t pick up the pieces, and
  >   Delicious traded it to me for a… uh… buff, wax, and sharpening.”
  >
  > <sub>*I Did NOT Give That Spider Superhuman Intelligence*</sub>
- Winnow, a particularly *nasty* supervillain, was mentioned in PDTMPIGH:

  > I went back to scratching my head with the scepter. “I’d need to see
  >   Mom’s statistics, but being a super hero if you hate it sounds like
  >   something that doesn’t turn out well.”
  >
  > “That’s how Winnow got started, yes,” said Bull. He and Irene both
  >   grimaced. Maybe I did, too. There was a name that went right at the
  >   top of the 'murderous psychopaths’ super powered list next to
  >   Judgment, and several steps up from Mourning Dove.
  >
  > <sub>*Please Don’t Tell My Parents I’ve Got Henchmen*</sub>

  And in IDNGTSSI:

  > I held up the left gauntlet, and sighed. Only the one. The other was
  >   in a tin can at the bottom of the ocean with Winnow, where Bull buried
  >   them.
  >
  > Probably not still with Winnow. There’s no containing that monster.
  >   Ugh. Do not go there, memory.
  >
  > <sub>*I Did NOT Give That Spider Superhuman Intelligence*</sub>
- Upgrades are mentioned:

  > Rachel and Ruth came galloping up to us on all fours. They were still
  >   mostly human. Their shoes were gone, split by massive claws, and they
  >   had a whole lot of sharp teeth in too-big mouths, but they were mostly
  >   furless. The silvery tattoos Cassie had called their Upgrade glowed,
  >   not even a little disguised.
  >
  > <sub>*Please Don’t Tell My Parents I’ve Got Henchmen*</sub>
- The villain Mammon, first mentioned in IDNGTSSI, now "reformed," appears in *Please Don’t Tell My Parents I Have a Nemesis*, the fourth book in the series.
- Lucyfar is mentioned, indirectly. It’s implied that Mammon summoned her:

  > Up above us, Mammon raged, “I don’t care! I’ve been refining my
  >   technique! My next summoning won’t be like the imps you see before
  >   you. With the sacrifice of a mother and child, I will draw from the
  >   infernal realm a being of black fire, a true fallen angel that will
  >   roast anyone Bradley sends against me. It’s all in the book, and I’m
  >   finally ready, and this time it will work!”
  >
  > <sub>*I Did NOT Give That Spider Superhuman Intelligence*</sub>

  Lucyfar can summon things out of what’s often described as “blackness” or “liquid black,” and claims to be a fallen angel. The reference to “black” fire specificially is a little too apt, so I’m guessing that this is Lucyfar.

**I didn’t see any reference to Brainy Akk or the Audit.**

Comment: Excellent work. I'm going to give a bit more time for references to trickle in, but I think that's it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots -  There’s also a reference to Evolution, but I wasn’t sure that was worth mentioning. Also, I looked carefully at all the children who were mentioned, and I couldn’t find anything to indicate that one of them was the Audit or Brainy Akk (it should have been fairly obvious).